# Passing Wildcard in sqoop arguments

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, sqoop

Currently I have,

> sqoop import --direct --connect jdbcURL --table Persons --columns `*` --username username --password password --target-dir /user/username/SqoopImportTest --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver -m 1

I know by default all the columns are picked up. But I want to use the same command for two jobs, one which picks up all columns and the other one a few columns. I wanted to keep `--columns *` as default. Is this possible?

Comment: No, It won't work that way. You can import few columns by giving --columns col1,col2,col3 or you can write your own query to get the columns you want by using --query , otherwise you need to import complete table

Answer (score 0):

Try 'options files' in Sqoop for dynamic query formation, that results Sqoop query/connection string.